# passing string to controller/action from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to lower the role of a user by clicking a link in my view.

When I click the link, it doesn't go to the action, but it just gives 404 error and links the resource that is not found with the string I am trying to pass to the action( referred to as "stringparameter")

In this case, the link is /Admin/Disable/stringparameter

I think I am not using the correct overload, so could someone help me out?
Thanks

This is the action in the AdminController

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Disable(string id)
    {
        Role rol = new UserRepository().GetRole("Disabled");             
        new UserRepository().UpdateUser(id,rol.RoleId);
        return RedirectToAction("Users");
    }
```

this is the viewmodel

```
public class UserSuperUserPM
{
    public UserClass User { get; set; }
    public List<UserClass> Users { get; set; }

    public UserClass SuperUser { get; set; }
    public List<UserClass> SuperUsers { get; set; }

    public UserClass Disabled { get; set; }
    public List<UserClass> Disableds { get; set; }

    public UserClass Inactive { get; set; }
    public List<UserClass> Inactives { get; set; }
}
```

this is the userclass

```
public class UserClass
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the view(1 of the 4 similar tables in the view)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username, Model.Users)
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role, Model.Users)
        </td>
        <td calss="col-md-4">
--------Commented attempted links(none of them work correct)
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Disable", "Disable", new { Controller = "Admin", action = "Disable", id = item.UserId })*@
            @*<a href="~/Controllers/AdminController/Disable?id=@item.UserId">Disable</a>*@
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Disable","Admin", new { id = item.UserId },null)*@
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Disable", "Disable","Admin", item.UserId)*@

-------original attempted link
            @Html.ActionLink("Disable", "Disable", new { id = item.UserId})




        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Your controller requires POST action, not GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `href` attr in a `a` element just do `GET` dont `POST`, so to it works change the Action to :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Disable(string id)
{
    Role rol = new UserRepository().GetRole("Disabled");             
    new UserRepository().UpdateUser(id,rol.RoleId);
    return RedirectToAction("Users");
}
```

But I suggest to you do this with JS.

Comment: oh silly me, forgetting it needs GET, thanks for pointing it out!
during the course we learned to do it like this, so for the sake of using my teacher's methods as i know them, i will keep using it like this, perhaps i can try JS on future projects, thanks for the tip ^^

Answer (score 1):

Just delete [HttpPost] it says that this controller only can be access by POST method an you are trying to access by GET, you should let it post and do the call with AJAx

Comment: oh silly me, forgetting it needs GET, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Shame on your cow. np XD